# How can test whether my IIS hosted server can communicate via TLS 1.2?

Tags: tls, iis-7.5

I've got a shared host running on Windows Server (waiting to hear whether it's 2008 or 2012) running either IIs7.5 or 8.x   (waiting on that too).

How can I easily test whether it's using (or at least capable of using) TLS 1.2 ?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use an online webstest like the free one from Qualys at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Answer (score 1):

You can use openssl to verify if your server supports TLS 1.2:

```
openssl s_client -connect mtak.nl:443 -tls1_2
```

If it supports TLS 1.2, your output will contain the following lines:

```
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```